# Computing the surface integral of the octant of a sphere with polar coordinate substitution

Tags: determinant, polar-coordinates, substitution, surface-integrals, stereographic-projections

**Let me first describe where I start:**

$$\iint_Sz^2\,dS$$
We want to compute the surface integral of the octant of a sphere $S$.
The radius = 1.
The sphere is centered at the origin.

$$S=x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$$

$$z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$
$R$ is the projection of $S$ on the $xy$-plane.

Now we compute the normalization factor used to project the integral on the $xy$-plane. First we compute the derivative  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$:

If
$$m=1-x^2-y^2$$
and
$$n=\sqrt{m}\,,$$
then the derivative of $n$ is
$$n'=\frac12m^{-\frac12},$$
and the derivative of $m$ (with regard to $x$) equal to:
$$m'=-2x.$$

Now we can compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ using the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=n'\cdot m'=\frac12m^{-\frac12}\cdot m'=\frac12(1-x^2-y^2)^{-\frac12}\cdot-2x=-{\frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)}}}.$$
Since $\sqrt{(1-x^2-y^2)}=z$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-{\frac xz}$$
And in the same manner (using the derivative of $m$ with regard to $y$) we can calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-{\frac yz}$$
Now we can calculate the normalization factor:
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2}=\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{y^2}{z^2}}=\frac1z\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$
Since $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$:
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2}=\frac1z$$

Now we can calculate the projection $R$ of the sphere $S$ on the $xy$-plane:
$$\iint_Sz^2\,dS=\iint_R z^2\frac1z \,dx\,dy=\iint_R z\;dx\,dy.$$
Substituting for $z$ finishes the conversion of the surface integral (remember $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$):
$$\iint_Sz^2dS=\iint_R \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\;dx\,dy.$$

**This is where my problem starts**:
The book I'm reading says if we convert this to polar coordinates, the integration should be trivial.

So we convert to polar coordinates:
$$x=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$
$$z=f(x,y)=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$
Calculate the Jacobian determinant:
$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}=\begin{vmatrix}\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & r\cos\theta\\ \end{vmatrix}=r\cos^2\theta+r\sin^2\theta=r\,(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta)=r$$
Substitute:
$$\iint_Sz^2dS=\iint_R \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\;dx\,dy=\iint_T\sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta}\cdot r \cdot dr\,d\theta$$
$$\iint_T\sqrt{1-r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)}\cdot r \cdot dr\,d\theta = \iint_T\sqrt{1-r^2}\cdot r \cdot dr\,d\theta=\iint_T\sqrt{r^2-r^4}\cdot dr\,d\theta$$

Since the radius $r=1$ it is easy to see that:
$$\int^1_0\sqrt{r^2-r^4}\cdot dr=\int^1_0(r^2-r^4)^{\frac12}\cdot dr = \int^1_0 \frac{(r^2-r^4)^{\frac32}}{\frac32}=0$$
**According to the book the result of the calculation of the surface of the sphere in the first octant should be $\pi/6$.**
That won't happen if $\int^1_0\sqrt{r^2-r^4}\cdot dr=0$.
The domain of $\theta$ is:
$$0\le\theta\le\frac12\pi$$
So where am I going wrong?

Comment: $\int\limits_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-r^2} \, r \, dr$ equals, after substituting $u = 1 -r^2$, $\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{1} \sqrt{u} \, du$, which in turn is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$.  And integrating in $\theta$ over the interval of length $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is equivalent to multiplying by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Everything is O.K.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. When you set $r\sin\theta$ and $r\cos\theta$ properly, you don't need manually added spacing between $r$ and $\cos$ or $\sin.$ I also added a small space before $dx$ or $dy$ or $dr$ or $d\theta$ in a number of cases, and changed $\displaystyle\int\int$ to $\displaystyle\iint. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the edits!

Comment: $$u=1-r^2$$  $$du=-2r\,dr$$  $$dr=-\frac{1}{2r}du$$  $$\int^1_0\sqrt{u} \cdot r \cdot -\frac{1}{2r}du$$  $$-\frac12\int^1_0\sqrt{u}\,du$$  Isn't the minus sign wrong?

Comment: To correct myself according to the answer given below:  $$\int^0_1\sqrt{u} \cdot r \cdot -\frac{1}{2r} du$$  $$-\frac12 \int^0_1 \sqrt{u} \,du$$  since $r=0$ means $u=1-r^2=1$ and $r=1$ means  $u=1-r^2=0$.

Comment: To complete my own comment:  $$\int^1_0\sqrt{1-r^2}\,r\,dr=-\frac12\int^0_1\sqrt{u}\,du$$

Comment: @ArthurSauer Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using the power rule

$$\int  (r^2 - r^4)^{1/2} dr= \frac{1}{3/2} (r^2 - r^4)^{3/2} +C,$$

but this is incorrect. Indeed if you differentiate the right hand side with respect to $r$, you do not get $(r^2 - r^4)^{1/2}$, but instead $(r^2 - r^4)^{1/2} (2r - 4r^3)$.

As noted in the comment, you can use substitution $u = 1-r^2$ to get

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2} rdr= -\frac 12 \int_1^0 \sqrt u du.$$

(we have $\int_1^0$ instead of $\int_0^1$ on the right hand side since you have to plug in the value accordingly: for $r=0$, you have $u= 1-r^2 = 1$, and for $r=1$ you get $u = 1-r^2 = 0$).

So you have

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2} dr = -\frac 12 \int_1^0 \sqrt u du = -\frac 13 u^{3/2}\bigg|_1^0 = \frac 13 $$

and thus $\int z^2 dS = \frac \pi 6$.

Comment: You are right I made a mistake using the power rule. Thanks!

Comment: This explains why you have to use substitution:  $$\int^1_0\sqrt{r^2-r^4}\cdot dr=\int^1_0(r^2-r^4)^{\frac12}\cdot dr = \int^1_0 \frac{1}{2r-4r^3} \cdot \frac{(r^2-r^4)^{\frac32}}{\frac32}=0$$  You get a division by 0.

Answer (score 0):

The surface integral is given by

$$\iint_S\,dS=\iint_R \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\;dx\,dy=$$

that is by polar coordinates

$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}\,d\theta\int_0^1 \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\,dr =\frac{\pi}2\left[-\sqrt{1-r^2}\right]_0^1=\frac{\pi}2$$

that is correct since the surface of the whole sphere is equal to $4\pi$.

The given integral is

$$\iint_Sz^2\,dS=\iint_R {\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\;dx\,dy=$$

that is by polar coordinates

$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}\,d\theta\int_0^1 r{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\, dr=\frac{\pi}2\left[-\frac13(1-r^2)^\frac32\right]_0^1=\frac{\pi}6$$

Answer (score 0):

The integration you are doind at last step is wrong. You can apply power rule for linear polynomial in $x$. For example you can do this $\int (4x + 2)$ or $\int (1-x)
$

But if there is quadratic polynomial in $x$, then there are different rules for integration. Usually you substitute. In you case there was quadratic polynomial in $x$ present with linear polynomial in $x$. So you know $d(x^2)=2x$. So put $x^2=t$